# Can you disable Windows Mail and 'one step login' via Windows Credentials?

Tags: windows-10, email, security, credentials

Can you disable Windows Mail and 'one step login' via Windows Credentials?

When I start up my desktop and login with my (simple) password, I can start up the windows mail program (that comes with the O.S.) with my outlook web account without having to submit my (complicated more secure) password for my web email. I do not want that. I do not even want to use that program.

What I tried so far is:

I removed the outlook account from the mail program. No use, you can just add it again. It still has remembered everything.

I think this is somehow arranged with Windows Credentials. That allows with one step: login to the system, to access among others my outlook mail account. There I could remove the SSO_POP_User of my outlook account. Then I restarted my desktop, but it just regenerated everything and I could open the mail program and use my outlook account again.

I can of course simply remove that program (Mail), but you can just reinstall it again. That probably has no use either.

I do not want someone that can enter my computer to also without an extra of security step access my web mail account. Far more security sensitive information is there. How can I prevent that? (And I passionately dislike that Mail program of the O.S.)

Answer (score 0):

> (I do not want someone that can enter my computer to also without an
> extra of security step access my web mail account)

You are confusing Windows Security with Mail Security.

Set your Windows login to be secure so no one can login in. Set Account settings to lock the computer after 10 minutes of no use.

Otherwise:

(a) I use Outlook and not Windows Mail and Windows Mail does not ever interfere.

(b) If a user want Windows Mail and not Outlook, then remove all Outlook accounts. You can remove the Windows Mail password and also remove Windows Mail from Startup to prevent it from starting when Windows starts.   Look in Start up Programs.  This does not require removing (uninstalling) Windows Mail.

(c) Outlook Web Mail is separate from all the above.

So:  Just set up carefully and only activate what you will use.